# How to code the sprintf_s method in C

Tags: printf

like the topic, I have no idea where to start with coding the sprintf_s method.
I tried to solve it with switch-case, but again, I have no idea where to start.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's where you start:

[**Documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx)

```
int sprintf_s(
   char *buffer,
   size_t sizeOfBuffer,
   const char *format, ...)
{
    int ret_val = 0;

    [...Fill stuff in here...]

    return ret_val;
}
```